# My grandmom died on 4th of feb 24. My marriage has been fixed on march 29,30 2024. Can marriage can still happen?

Tags: upanishads, rig-veda, panchang, chinna-jeeyar

my grandmom is dead (4th feb 24) and my marriage was fixed on 29,30 march 2024. When we ask pandits, everyone has their different opinions and we are so confused. Couple of them say can happen and some of them say atleast need to wait for 45 days. Can someone plz help. Really stuck

Comment: No .. all auspicious functions has to be put on hold for one year from the date of demise.